# Doesn't update selectedItem in custom dropdown

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

Suppose to have this dropdown:

```
 <p-dropdown [options]="list" [(ngModel)]="code">
                    <ng-template let-item pTemplate="selectedItem">
                        {{ item.value }} - {{ item.label }}
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
                        {{ item.value }} - {{ item.label }}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-dropdown>
```

and in my ts I have:

```
//loadValue in an object that I have just loaded with this attribute({label, value]}
//list is a list with current dropdown list and it is in this way ({label,vale}]
let index= this.list.findIndex(x => x['value'] === this.loadValue['value']);
        this.code= this.list[index];
```

The problem is that `list`,`loadValue` and `index` are correct calculate, but the selectedItem value is not update because it show me the first value of the list but it is not correct result.

Comment: where are you using selectedItem in the ts file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the item to your ngModel instead of the value.
You need to pass the value. This is obviously a problem however if you think it is not getting updated after your assignment you need to debug what's the actual behavior.

```
this.code= this.list[index].value;
```